# Reading the date picker selected value lost

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have implemented date picker using [Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/). Using this library, I have setting up the date picker by the following code in the `component.html` template of Angular 2 component.

```
<input type="text" class="date-picker form-control" id="expect_comp_date"
         name="expect_comp_date" [(ngModel)]="model.expect_comp_date" #expect_comp_date="ngModel">
```

[image: The Prolem I have face on this gif showcase]

Here If I click the clander date the date is shown in the text box. When I trigger the submit button the date is not send to the POST request.

If I enteres some value on the text box and delete after send the POST request the date value is successfully send via POST request.

Why It is happen? How do I read the value by only select the date time picker dialog.

My Service Provider for Sending POST request is as follow

```
createNewJob(model: Job) {
var params = JSON.stringify({
  job_code: model.job_code,
  customer_id: model.customer_id,
  expect_comp_date: model.expect_comp_date,
  actual_comp_date: model.actual_comp_date,
  job_note: model.job_note,
  service_requests: []
});

var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post('[MY_POST_REQUEST_URL]', params, {headers: headers})
  .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: How are you sending the POST request? The [(ngModel)] should bind to the variable model.expect_comp_date.

Comment: I have updated in the question